# How to extract the href attribute from an anchor element and match it with the url, to add a class the the tag if they match

Tags: php, wordpress, url, href

Today I want to check my urls and my href attributes to see if they match, and in that case, I want to add a wrap to my anchor element that owns the href attribute in a  tag with php in a wordpress enviroment (not with javascript, it has to happen before the page load).

Here's my code so far:

I've already tried to do with php only, but I'm having some problem in get the last element of the url.

Essentially the next step should be wrap the html in php (echo) and try to see if my url match with the href.

```
<?php
$url_parse = wp_parse_url( 'https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_url/' );

echo $url_parse['path'];
?>
<aside>
  <button class="mobile-tabs">Navigation <i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-down"></i>
  </button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a title="admission" href="/admissions/">Admissions</a></li>
      <li><a title="How to apply" href="/admissions/how-to-apply/">How to Apply</a></li>
      <li><a title="Financing" href="/admissions/financing/">Financing</a></li>
      <li><a title="SECC Scholarship" href="/admissions/secc-scholarship/">SECC Scholarship</a></li>
      <li><a title="Second Career Funding" href="/admissions/second-career-funding/">Second Career Funding</a></li>
      <li><a title="Canada Job Grant" href="/admissions/canada-job-grant/">Canada Job Grant</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

My goal is to write a code like that:

```
if ($url_parse == href) {
   echo '<strong>'.'<a>my element</a>.'</strong>';
} else {
  echo '<a>my element</a>';
}
```

Comment: Match url with href with php to add a class to an anchor sidebar element?

I need to extract the href and match it with the uri, and wrap the element if they match

Comment: I think he wants to highlight `<a>` elements that link to the current page.

Comment: actually wrap them, but with php. I know how to do it in javascript. I can describe how to do that..